# Node.js - Express routing endpoint to Object Key Value inside array

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url, backend

I have a local server that I have created to learn and practice my backend coding. Right now its in the early stages of becoming a "netflix" style app. I have a code:

```
app.get("/movies/:title", (req, res) => {
res.json(movies.find((movie) => {
    return movie.title === req.params.title
}));
```

});

that when I type this URL: localhost:8080/movies/:title (insert title name) it returns the desired movie form this array:

```
let movies = [
    //1
{
    title: 'Lord of the Rings',
    actor: 'Orlando',
    genre: 'adventure',
    director: 'person'

} ,
//2
{
    title: 'Harry Potter',
    actor: 'Daniel Radcliffe',
    genre: 'Fantasy',
    director: 'person',
    Movie_ID: "7"
} ,
//3
{
    title: 'Imaginaerum',
    actor: 'Toumas Holopainen',
    genre: 'Fiction',
    director: 'person',
    Movie_ID: "1"
} ,
//4
{
    title: 'Cloud Atlas',
    actor: 'Person',
    genre: 'Fantasy',
    director: 'person'
}
```

However, when I try to do the same, but with the key value "actor" in this URL:
localhost:8080/movies/:actor (replace for actor name)

nothing shows up. Here is the code for that:

```
app.get("/movies/:actor", (req, res) => {
console.log(req.params)
res.json(movies.find(movie => {
    return movie.actor === req.params.actor
}));
});
```

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but `===` is case-sensitive, so you might want to say `return move.actor.toLowerCase() === req.params.actor.toLowerCase();`

Comment: `/movies/:actor` and `/movies/:title` are actually the same route, all requests go to the block that is declared first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Đăng Khoa Đinh explained, these are the same routes, so your code doesn't know which end point to use.

Change one to:

`/movies/actor/:actor/` and the other to `/movies/title/:title` or a similar change to get this working.